# wget fails to exclude directories

Tags: wget

I want to download files from a site, but I want to exclude specific directories. I am using the following command:

```
wget --user="xxxx" --password="xxx" -r -np -nH --cut-dirs=7 \
  --reject "index.html*" --exclude-directories=/abc/xyz/pqr/a \
  https://www.ftpsite.com/abc/xyz/pqr/
```

Under the `pqr/` directory there are 3 directories, out of which I want to exclude directory `a`.

But using the above command, it downloads all 3 directories even after specifying the exclude-directory option.

Comment: what happens if you specify the directories using relative paths instead of absolute?

Comment: @Jakuje even if after specifying --exclude-directories=/a , i got same result.

Comment: relative is without the leading `/`.

Comment: @Jakuje same result by using --exclude-directories=a

Comment: What happens if you use the fully qualified domain name in the exclusion?  `https://www.ftpsite.com/abc/xyz/pqr/a/*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. Actually command mentioned in question works properly....
Problem was: when space is there in URL then after entering URL space was getting converted to '%20' character.

I was using same URL with '%20' character to download using wget. Download was successful with '%20' character...But --exclude-directories wasn't working with '%20', so I replaced %20 with space(' ') and it worked...

Anyway thanks for your help and suggestions provided in comments.